# Transforming the Title Element's Text

Tags: html, css, browser, title, styling

Is it possible to "reflect" the title text of the browser window? For example the word "mirror" would become "rorrim" with the characters **also facing the opposite direction**. It's OK if it doesn't work in every browser, but asking the user to install something isn't an option.

Thanks!

Comment: You mean, in the window's title bar? Can you show a sketch of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes, the text in the window's title bar.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not opposed to plain javascript, you could add this after the `title` tag.  Make sure to give the `title` an `id` of title.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    var title = document.getElementById("title").innerHTML;
    var titlechange = title.split('').reverse().join('');
    var title = document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = titlechange;
</script>
```

Comment: Reversing the text does not change the direction the characters are facing.

Answer (score 0):

The following uses the value from an `input` field and outputs it's value concatenated with it's value reversed.

```
String.prototype.reverse = function() {
    return this.split('').reverse().join('');
};

$("#wintitle").keyup(function(){
    var newtitle = $(this).val() + ' - ' + $(this).val().reverse();
    document.title = newtitle;
    $("#output span").html(document.title);
});
```

**Demo: [jsfiddle.net/42umy](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/42umy/show)** ([edit](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/42umy/))

Comment: Reversing the text does not change the direction the characters are facing.

Comment: @moorej: Ah OK, then no can do.

Answer (score -1):

The title text cannot be styled in any way. In IE9, however there is a plugin called [classic shell](http://classicshell.sourceforge.net/)
It wont do what you are asking though.

Comment: So...why do you link to a plug-in that won't do what [the OP is] asking?

Comment: Oh well. So now we downvote the above 2 solutons which "won't do what [the OP is] asking?"

Comment: I have no idea, but I didn't downvote you. I left the comment as a prompt for you to improve, or delete, your answer.

Comment: I know David. Dont much care about the votes. As far as I know, the title element can not be styled in anway. Thanks. Will take care next time. Cheers!